# Launch multiple applications with a single double click on Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: node.js, bash, sh, ubuntu-20.04, gnome-terminal

I have a single Ubuntu Desktop running

1. a static server (React),
2. a node server (API),
3. an instance of Zoom Client,
4. an instance of OBS, and
5. a browser pointed to the static server.

Currently, a sh script intended to launch everything executes with a double click. Three applications launch as desired.

```
#! /bin/bash
PORT=3000
URL="http://localhost:$PORT/controller"
gnome-terminal --tab --../repo/church/ts-cam-app/startUI.sh
gnome-terminal --tab --../repo/church/CamCtrlServer/startSvr.sh
obs --startvirtualcam --scene "Live"  &
zoom &
microsoft-edge $URL
```

**My problem:** I haven’t been able execute two other sh scripts, each residing in their respective directories, to launch the React and API services. The static server launches from the

**Useless "why" information:** The Ubuntu Desktop is located behind a firewall that I don’t have access to open a public port on and forward to the Ubuntu machine. However, at some future point, I plan to add a publicly accessible server to relay requests to the current one (behind the firewall). That will allow me to separate the most of the services from that current box.

Comment: Your question appears truncated.  Also you tell us what works but nothing about what doesn't work.  So why can't you run those two other scripts (from this one)?  Do you need to change directory (cd) then run it.

Comment: Sure. What doesn't work is the execution of the "serve -s" to launch the static server, and "npm start" to launch the Node Express server.

Comment: Again. What doesn't work is the correct execution of the startUI.sh script, which contains a "serve -s" command to launch the static server. The second script, startSvr.sh, doesn't execute at all. It contains an "node npm start" command to launch the Node Express server.
What I expect: 
    Two new terminal instances should open in new tabs. Only one opens, but it executes the command in the directory of the launch script. Previously I used 
`cd ../repo/church/ts-cam-app` before calling the script, but then nothing executed.
Again, the 2nd new tab for the second script called never opens.

Comment: You are running `gnome-terminal` in the foreground, so the script waits for you to close that terminal. The immediate fix is to add `&` to run it in the background. A much, much much better fix is to get rid of the terminals and log all output to log files.